# Spring 3.1 and Hibernate 4: "HibernateException: No Session found for current thread" When calling DAO method from unit test

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, unit-testing, exception

I'm using Spring 3.1 and Hibernate 4.1, and I'm currently getting the following exception when I run a repository test:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Session found for current thread
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.SpringSessionContext.currentSession(SpringSessionContext.java:97)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.getCurrentSession(SessionFactoryImpl.java:1041)
```

Here's what a DAO looks like. It uses the same generics dao pattern that basically everyone else is using:

```
@Repository
public class UserRepository extends RepositorySupport<User> {

    public UserRepository() {
        super(User.class);
    }

    public User findByUsername(final String username) {
        Query query = getCurrentSession().createQuery(
            "from User user " +
            "where user.username = :username"
        );

        return (User) query.setParameter("username", username)
            .uniqueResult();
    }
```

The only thing different here that I normally wouldn't do is that I am not using `getHibernateTemplate()` anymore - and that's why I suspect things aren't working. I'd rather not use this method if I can avoid it, as the resultant code looks horrible.

My hibernate beans look like this:

```
<bean id="sessionFactory"
      class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="mappingResources">
        <list>
            <value>hibernate/tag.hbm.xml</value>
            <value>hibernate/address.hbm.xml</value>
            <value>hibernate/user.hbm.xml</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="namingStrategy">
        <bean class="org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy"/>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="javax.persistence.validation.mode">none</prop>

            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">${hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto}
            </prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.generate_statistics">false</prop>

            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</prop>

            <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">false</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.provider_class">

            </prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateExceptionTranslator"/>

<bean id="transactionManager"
      class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
</bean>

<!--
<bean id="hibernateInterceptor"
      class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateInterceptor">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
</bean>
-->

<tx:advice id="transactionAdvice" transaction-manager="transactionManager">
    <tx:attributes>
        <tx:method name="find*" read-only="true" propagation="REQUIRED"/>
        <tx:method name="get*" read-only="true" propagation="REQUIRED"/>
        <tx:method name="*" propagation="REQUIRED"/>
    </tx:attributes>
</tx:advice>

<aop:config>
    <aop:advisor advice-ref="transactionAdvice"
                 pointcut="execution(* *..service.*.*(..))" order="1"/>
    <!-- gets sub packages like service.user -->
    <aop:advisor advice-ref="transactionAdvice"
                 pointcut="execution(* *..service.*.*.*(..))" order="2"/>
</aop:config>

<bean id="validator"
      class="org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean"/>

<context:annotation-config/>
<context:spring-configured/>
<context:component-scan base-package="com.realtywebsite.repositories,com.realtywebsite.service"/>

<task:annotation-driven />
```

My test code looks something like this (I have to flatten it because my tests extend from a common parent test class):

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {
    ObjectMother.APPLICATION_CONTEXT,
    ObjectMother.WEB_CONTEXT
})
public abstract class DatabaseTest extends AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests {


    @Test
    public void delete() {
        userRepository.delete(1);
        flush();

        assertFalse(userRepository.exists(1));
    }

    ...
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The class `AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests` is deprecated.

You have two choices:

- extend from `AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests`, or
- use `SpringJUnit4ClassRunner` (then you need to attach `@Transactional`)

*I hope that would fix the problem.*

Answer (score 0):

I had such problems migrating from hibernate 3 to hibernate 4. In short, there is no provider to open and bind hibernate session to current thread. So sessionFactory will have no currentSession (as it is stored in ThreadLocal variable). The most popular way to solve it for web applications is to use [OpenSessionInViewInterceptor](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/1.1.4/api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate/support/OpenSessionInViewInterceptor.html) or [OpenSessionInViewFilter](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate4/support/OpenSessionInViewFilter.html). In your case I would suggest you to write your own. [Here is an example.](http://thediningphilosopher.blogspot.com/2008/10/hibernate-session-and-transaction-with.html)

Comment: I'm using that for UI. The problem is with a @PostConstruct bean that is executed when the tests are run :(